# Moving LPF's in UDK

Tags: udk, video-games, guns, implementation

Anyone work in UDK much?

If so, I have a question for you.

If a guy shoots a gun on one end of the map, on a basic concept, the player on the other end of the map should hear it differently.

This can be done (on a basic level) by tagging either the gun, the gun audio cue, or the player model itself with a LPF radius so that anything beyond the radius should sound "farther" away based on a LPF roll-off.

My question is - How do you tag this LPF radius to the gun sound within this certain circumstance of "distance rolloff" audio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing i'm not entirley sure what you're trying to do. I'l quickly explain the two ways you can deal with distance based content in the UDK.
Both are pretty simple to implement.

1. In the sound cue for the weapon add an attenuation node and in the Low Pass Filter tab check "Attenuate With LPF" and set up the radii of attenuation.
2. Have several different distance versions of the same weapon sound (close, med, far) and use the distance crossfade node in the sound cue to mix between each of these.

Both can be used to do what you want. The second one is a little more difficult to set up and has a bigger ram footprint but in the end will sound better.

Comment: @Andrew Nice - ill try the first for the time being, and start working on the 2nd for a more polished sound. I knew there had to be the first option available - what audio engine would not have such a thing, as basic as it is. Thanks for the tips!